# jboss 7 http connector to support byte range headers

Tags: http, jboss, header, range

In a jboss 7 with http connector , the http range header does not work.

For example, a request like the following:

```
curl -isk --range 0-20 http://www.sitename.com/filename
```

returns a response like the following and the whole file, not just the first 20 bytes of the file.

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
```

The correct response should have been like:

```
HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content
```

How can I make jboss 7 to handle correctly the "Range" requests in it's http connector ?